# Strange buzzing/feedback on distortion

Tags: electric-guitar

Recently I bought a second hand LTD EC-1000ET (evertune) which was and is in mint condition, though I've just noticed this strange issue when using distortion. I have included a link which illustrates the noise. I have no idea why this is happening, but some things to note are:

- I use 10-46 in Drop D while the previous owner used gauge 12 in E flat (I believe)
- The buzzing isn't audible on clean channels and less audible when not palm-muting
- Buzzing is most prominent on the low E
- Strings are muted with some foam behind the nut
- I use amp sims like BIAS FX and Amplitube 4 with the audio interface Behringer UMC202HD (which was a B-stock)
- Buzzing occurs on both neck and bridge pickups
- I have tried to: tighten screws, adjust pickup height, adjust truss rod and adjust (bridge) action; all to no avail
- I have also noticed that the nut action might be slightly too low, though I'm thinking of taking it to a technician to confirm

This is all I can think of off the top of my head. If you need pics of my BIAS FX preset, I can post if necessary. Also, I don't know if the problem is with that particular guitar or something else (like my interface etc), but I've included a second link demonstrating the sound of my Jackson JS22 using the same setup just to compare. Thanks.

- LTD

- Jackson

Comment: I can't hear any buzzing there at all. Just better sustain on the LTD than the JS. Can you provide a sample without the distortion

Comment: @DoktorMayhem From what I can tell, it sounds perfectly fine without distortion (on a clean channel) and the 'buzzing' I suppose is that extra feedback I get after hitting a note. The problem with it is that when I play many palm-muted notes in quick succession (especially with a double track), it sounds all messy because I'm getting all that extra noise... Am I just crazy or is it really not audible?

Comment: It's either not audible, or doesn't match your description so other people are not recognising what you mean. If you mean the hanging harmonic, then you need tighter damping. Your hand might be right where the harmonic can still ring, move an inch closer to the fretboard.